# Create basic swiper.js class which could be extended for multiple sliders

Tags: javascript, oop, swiper.js

I try to create a basic swiper class which could be extended to create multiple swipers with different content.

I get the json array with required data (video id, video src and description), then call the swiper instance whith variables and functions I declared in javascript. The script creates number of slides based on the array elements quantity and inserting there info from json data.

What I try to achive is a basic class which could be extended as a different instance of swiper. My class extension seems not to be properly created.

```js
class medigitSlider {
    constructor(params) {

        if (document.querySelector('.swiper')) {
        // function, which initializes the swiper with required class names, which are set in the array I got
            this.init = function (params) {
                this.sliders = params.sliders;
                this.swiperDiv = params.swiperDiv;
                this.swiperName = params.swiperName;
                this.navPrev = params.navPrev;
                this.navNext = params.navNext;
            };

            this.showSlider = function () {
                let swiperWrapper = document.querySelector(this.swiperDiv);
                // cycle to create the number of slides based on the got json array
                for (let i = 0; i < this.sliders.length; i++) {
                    // creating swiper slide div
                    let swiperSlide = document.createElement('div');
                    // creating video description little modal
                    let videoDesc = document.createElement('div');

                    // adding classes to the little modal with video description
                    videoDesc.classList.add('slide-inside-modal');
                    videoDesc.textContent = this.sliders[i].description;

                    // adding classes to the slide div
                    swiperSlide.classList.add('swiper-slide', 'fluidMedia');
                    // adding slides to the swiper-wrapper div
                    swiperWrapper.append(swiperSlide);
                    // creating little modal window with video description
                    swiperSlide.append(videoDesc);

                    // creating iframe
                    let frameEl = document.createElement('iframe');
                    // removing frame borders
                    frameEl.frameBorder = '0';
                    // adding empty iframe into the slide
                    swiperSlide.append(frameEl);
                }

                // method, integrating src into video frame of the visible slide and deleting videos from invisible slides
                let gallerySwiper = new Swiper(this.swiperName, {
                    centeredSlides: true,
                    spaceBetween: 30,
                    navigation: {
                        nextEl: params.navPrev,
                        prevEl: params.navNext,
                    }
                });

                gallerySwiper.on('slideChange', () => {
                    this.loadFrameSrc(gallerySwiper.activeIndex);
                });
                // initializing first video load
                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                    this.loadFrameSrc(gallerySwiper.activeIndex);
                });

                // functionality of showing / hiding window
                let slideModals = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-inside-modal'); 

                // getting all the slides on the page
                let allSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide');

                // cycle iterates trough the allSlides variables
                for (let slide of allSlides) {
                    // listening to the moment when the mouse enter the slide
                    slide.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
                        for (let slideModal of slideModals) {
                            slideModal.style.transform = 'translateY(20px)';
                        }
                    });
                    // listening to the moment when the mouse leave the slide
                    slide.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
                        for (let slideModal of slideModals) {
                            slideModal.style.transform = 'translateY(-50px)';
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

            // function describing video loading inside the frame
            this.loadFrameSrc = function (index) {
                let frames = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
                // delete videos from slides which are not visible
                for (let frame of frames) {
                    frame.src = '';
                }

                // add link into src attribute inside active slide
                frames[index].src = this.sliders[index].url;
            };

            this.init(params);
            this.showSlider();
        }

    }
}

// here is how I try to extend previously created class
class anotherMedigitSlider extends medigitSlider {
    constructor(params) {
        super(params)

        this.init(params)
        this.showSlider();
    }

    
}
```

```css
/* Swiper Styles */
.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
  
    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  /* .swiper-slide img {
    display: block;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 400px;
    object-fit: cover;
  } */
  
  .swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  
  video {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  iframe,
  embed,
  object {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  
  .vendor {
    padding: 2%;
  }
  
  .unsupported {
    background: #fddfde;
  }
  
  .fluidMedia {
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    /* proportion value to aspect ratio 16:9 (9 / 16 = 0.5625 or 56.25%) */
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .fluidMedia iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .slide-inside-modal,
  .slide-inside-modal-2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999999;
    color: #fff;
    transform: translateY(-50px);
    padding: 20px 0;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39);
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .inside-modal-show {
    transform: translateY(22px);
  }
  
  .swiper-button-next {
    right: 25px !important;
  }
  
  .swiper-button-prev {
    left: 25px !important;
  }
  
  .swiper-button-prev:after {
    content: url("./img/arrow_left.svg") !important;
  }
  
  .swiper-button-next::after {
    content: url("./img/arrow_right.svg") !important;
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 500px) {
    .slide-inside-modal,
    .slide-inside-modal-2 {
      transform: translateY(22px);
    }
  }


/* Swiper Styles End */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Just a swiper div, nothing serious -->
<div class="swiper mySwiper">
                  <div class="swiper-wrapper"></div>
                  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
        <script>
        /* This is the script assinging swiper attributes on the web page */
        BX.ready(function () {
         (new medigitSlider(<?=Json::encode([
                'sliders' => $arUrls,
                'swiperName' => '.mySwiper',
                'swiperDiv' => '.swiper-wrapper',
                'navPrev' => '.swiper-button-prev',
                'navNext' => '.swiper-button-next',
         ])?>
         ));
        });
        </script>
```

I have succeded creating one instance of swiper and the slider works fine while it's alone, but I cannot properly display multiple instances of swiper.